# cost of using adwords api for managing ads

Tags: api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to find out what using the AdWords API costs before digging into it - as I don't see the fun in blowing a budget on getting code to set up only to find it's too expensive to run.

The scenario:

- List item
- we've got a number of campaigns with a total of about 50,000 keywords
- we want to manage these keywords as automatic as possible (which essentially means getting current info about the keywords, settings status for keywords - pausing them if needed - and managing bids)

Basically, this means querying the API service for info on all adgroups, updating specific ads or keywords as needed.

Am I correct in reading the http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/ratesheet.html to mean that getting info for keywords is 1 unit per keyword, meaning a minimum spend of 50,000 units to get the info? Is there an option that doesn't suck up units like there's no tomorrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI google preferred pricing is retired .. they are providing api for free with two levels of access.

> Based on feedback we've heard, and to encourage continued innovation,
>   we are making AdWords API usage free for developers, starting March 1,
>   2013. Adwords API preferred pricing will be retired.
>
> Going forward, there will be two levels of API access: Basic and
>   standard. Basic access is provided by default and allows up to 10,000
>   operations per day. Standard access is available to qualified
>   developers and has no daily limit on operations. With either basic or
>   standard access, there will be no charges for AdWords API usage.

for more info http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/01/new-simplified-adwords-api-pricing.html

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from Google - http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api/browse_thread/thread/03992636b7dc99ce/0816836f826cbd1d?lnk=raot#0816836f826cbd1d

> Retrieving 50000 keywords using AdGroupCriterionService will cost you 50000 
>   API units as per the rate sheet. Instead, you can use a keyword performance 
>   report to pull your keywords and their stats. You can create one report 
>   definition for 400 units and download the report daily; report download 
>   won't cost you any API units. Updating the status and budgets will cost you 
>   API units, but chances are that those costs are lesser since you may not 
>   update 50000 keywords every day.

So there's definitely a better way to query the data